# Elasticsearch read_only_allow_delete auto setting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have problem with Elasticsearch. I tried the following:

```bash
 $ curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings \
       -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": false}'
```

My settings:

```json
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "blocks": {
      "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
    },
    "provided_name": "new-index",
    "creation_date": "1515433832692",
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "ngram_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "4"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "ngram_filter"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "uuid": "OSG7CNAWR9-G3QC75K4oQQ",
    "version": {
      "created": "6010199"
    }
  }
}
```

When I check settings it looks fine, but only a few seconds (3-5) and it's still set to `true`. I can't add new elements and query anything, only `_search` and `delete`.

Someone have any idea how to resolve this?

**NOTE:** I'm using Elasticsearch version: 6.1.1

Comment: @lomboboo yes, I have less than 15% free space on my disc and it was reason why this option auto set to true

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Elasticsearch automatically sets `"read_only_allow_delete": "true"` when hard disk space is low.

Find the files which are filling up your storage and delete/move them. Once you have sufficient storage available run the following command through the Dev Tool in Kibana:

```
PUT your_index_name/_settings
{
 "index": {
   "blocks": {
     "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

**OR** (through the terminal):

```
$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings \
     -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": false}'
```

as mentioned in your question.

Comment: Hi! We are getting disk space problems and we have a lot of indexes. Until we get some more disk space I have to almost daily delete some indexes/document and the run  the "read_only_allow_delete":"false". Running it so many times through Kibana takes a lot of time. The question is: Running through terminal that curl (I see there is a "_all" will restore to true the read only allow delete on ALL the indexes? Our ElasticSearch version is 6.3.0 and in the documentation I see "_all" is deprecated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you know how much memory will trigger this issue?

Comment: Where is minimum disc space is definded?

Comment: @hd it not explicit defined. Elasticsearch need more than 15% of whole disc space

Comment: the solution should be setting `{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}` instead of false (false is default for this setting so there is no need to explicitly set false)

Comment: I used this answer more than 10 times :D
Many thanks.

Comment: Powershell: `Invoke-WebRequest -Met Put -ContentType application/json http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -Body (@{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"=$null;}|ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 17):

In an attempt to add a sprinkling of value to the accepted answer (and because i'll google this and come back in future), for my case the `read_only_allow_delete` flag was set because of the default settings for disk watermark being percentage based - which on my large disk did not make as much sense. So I changed these settings to be "size remaining" based [as the documentation explains](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html).

So before setting `read_only_allow_delete` back to `false`, I first set the watermark values based on disk space:

(using Kibana UI):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "20gb",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "15gb",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "10gb"
  }
}

PUT your_index_name/_settings
{
 "index": {
   "blocks": {
     "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

OR (through the terminal):

```
$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:9200/_cluster/_settings \
   -d '{"cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "20gb", 
     "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "15gb", 
     "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "10gb"}'

$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings \
   -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": false}'
```

Comment: is it  `http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings` or http://localhost:9200/_cluster/_settings? Is there any difference between `_settings`  and `settings`?

Comment: nevermind, `_cluster/_settings` does not work in Elasticsearch (at least version 7), the correct is `_cluster/settings`.

Comment: the above will also be remove when elasticsearch is restarted, instead of `transient`, use `persistent`

Answer (score 2):

#### Background

We maintain a cluster where we have filebeat, metricbeat, packetbeat, etc. shippers pushing data into the cluster. Invariably some index would become hot and we'd want to either disable writing to it for a time or do clean up and reenable indices which had breached their low watermark thresholds and had automatically gone into `read_only_allow_delete: true`.

#### Bash Functions

To ease the management of our clusters for the rest of my team I wrote the following Bash functions to help perform these tasks without having to fumble around with `curl` or through Kibana's UI.

```
$ cat es_funcs.bash

### es wrapper cmd inventory
declare -A escmd
escmd[l]="./esl"
escmd[p]="./esp"

### es data node naming conventions
nodeBaseName="rdu-es-data-0"
declare -A esnode
esnode[l]="lab-${nodeBaseName}"
esnode[p]="${nodeBaseName}"

usage_chk1 () {
    # usage msg for cmds w/ 1 arg
    local env="$1"

    [[ $env =~ [lp] ]] && return 0 || \
        printf "\nUSAGE: ${FUNCNAME[1]} [l|p]\n\n" && return 1
}

enable_readonly_idxs () {
    # set read_only_allow_delete flag
    local env="$1"
    usage_chk1 "$env" || return 1
    DISALLOWDEL=$(cat <<-EOM
        {
         "index": {
           "blocks": {
             "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
            }
          }
        }
    EOM
    )
    ${escmd[$env]} PUT '_all/_settings' -d "$DISALLOWDEL"
}

disable_readonly_idxs () {
    # clear read_only_allow_delete flag
    local env="$1"
    usage_chk1 "$env" || return 1
    ALLOWDEL=$(cat <<-EOM
        {
         "index": {
           "blocks": {
             "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
            }
          }
        }
    EOM
    )
    ${escmd[$env]} PUT '_all/_settings' -d "$ALLOWDEL"
}
```

#### Example Run

The above functions can be sourced in your shell like so:

```
$ . es_funcs.bash
```

**NOTE:** The arrays at the top of the file map short names for clusters if you happen to have multiple. We have 2, one for our lab and one for our production. So I represented those as `l` and `p`.

You can then run them like this to enable the `read_only_allow_delete` attribute (true) on your `l` cluster:

```
$ enable_readonly_idxs l
{"acknowledged":true}
```

or `p`:

```
$ enable_readonly_idxs p
{"acknowledged":true}
```

#### Helper Script Overview

There's one additional script that contains the `curl` commands which I use to interact with the clusters. This script is referenced in the `escmd` array at the top of the `es_func.bash` file. The array contains names of symlinks to a single shell script, `escli.bash`. The links are called `esl` and `esp`.

```
$ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 smingolelli staff  9035 Apr 10 23:38 es_funcs.bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 smingolelli staff  1626 Apr 10 23:02 escli.bash
-rw-r--r-- 1 smingolelli staff   338 Apr  5 00:27 escli.conf
lrwxr-xr-x 1 smingolelli staff    10 Jan 23 08:12 esl -> escli.bash
lrwxr-xr-x 1 smingolelli staff    10 Jan 23 08:12 esp -> escli.bash
```

The `escli.bash` script:

```
$ cat escli.bash
#!/bin/bash

#------------------------------------------------
# Detect how we were called [l|p]
#------------------------------------------------
[[ $(basename $0) == "esl" ]] && env="lab1" || env="rdu1"

#------------------------------------------------
# source escli.conf variables
#------------------------------------------------
# g* tools via brew install coreutils
[ $(uname) == "Darwin" ] && readlink=greadlink || readlink=readlink
. $(dirname $($readlink -f $0))/escli.conf


usage () {
    cat <<-EOF

    USAGE: $0 [HEAD|GET|PUT|POST] '...ES REST CALL...'

    EXAMPLES:

        $0 GET  '_cat/shards?pretty'
        $0 GET  '_cat/indices?pretty&v&human'
        $0 GET  '_cat'
        $0 GET  ''
        $0 PUT  '_all/_settings'   -d "\$DATA"
        $0 POST '_cluster/reroute' -d "\$DATA"


    EOF
    exit 1
}

[ "$1" == "" ] && usage

#------------------------------------------------
# ...ways to call curl.....
#------------------------------------------------
if [ "${1}" == "HEAD" ]; then
    curl -I -skK \
        <(cat <<<"user = \"$( ${usernameCmd} ):$( ${passwordCmd} )\"") \
        "${esBaseUrl}/$2"
elif [ "${1}" == "PUT" ]; then
    curl -skK \
        <(cat <<<"user = \"$( ${usernameCmd} ):$( ${passwordCmd} )\"") \
        -X$1 -H "${contType}" "${esBaseUrl}/$2" "$3" "$4"
elif [ "${1}" == "POST" ]; then
    curl -skK \
        <(cat <<<"user = \"$( ${usernameCmd} ):$( ${passwordCmd} )\"") \
        -X$1 -H "${contType}" "${esBaseUrl}/$2" "$3" "$4"
else
    curl -skK \
        <(cat <<<"user = \"$( ${usernameCmd} ):$( ${passwordCmd} )\"") \
        -X$1 "${esBaseUrl}/$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"
fi
```

This script takes a single property file, `escli.conf`. In this file you specify the commands to retrieve your username + password from whereever, I use LastPass for that so retrieve them via `lpass` as well as setting the base URL to use for accessing your clusters REST API.

```
$ cat escli.conf
#################################################
### props used by escli.bash
#################################################

usernameCmd='lpass show --username somedom.com'
passwordCmd='lpass show --password somedom.com'

esBaseUrl="https://es-data-01a.${env}.somdom.com:9200"
contType="Content-Type: application/json"
```

I've put all this together in a Github repo (linked below) which also includes additional functions beyond the above 2 that I'm showing as examples for this question.

#### References

- https://github.com/slmingol/escli